# Table Relatioships

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, table-relationships

Hi guys I have a problem with simple dataset

In the table I get the same results for the count of Child friendly resort whether is by country or by continent.

My model seem to be in good shape since it doesn't happen with values from other columns

this is the measure being used

Count of Children friendly resorts = calculate(
COUNTROWS(
'Resort Classification Dim'),
Filter(
ALL(
'Resort Classification Dim'),
'Resort Classification Dim'[Child Friendly]=TRUE)

```
                                   )
```

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klI0i.png)
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUOHz.png)

I tried changing the data type from true or false to text so I can try using countx on the measure  but didn't make a difference

any advice?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you do ALL you are clearing the filter context on the table, you don't want to do that. Can be changed to:

```
Count of Children friendly resorts = calculate( COUNTROWS( 'Resort Classification Dim'), Filter('Resort Classification Dim'),
'Resort Classification Dim'[Child Friendly]=TRUE))
```

or simply

```
Count of Children friendly resorts = calculate( COUNTROWS( 'Resort Classification Dim'),'Resort Classification Dim'[Child Friendly]=TRUE)
```